# Finding the remainder after dividing $2^{2^{17}} + 1$ by $19$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Can you please give me any hints for finding the modulo of the division of $\large \displaystyle 2^{2^{17}} + 1$ with the number $19$. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome, darkchampionz! We encourage posters to accept an answer they receive if an answer has been helpful. You can accept one answer per question: to accept an answer, click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. You get two reputation points each time you accept an answer to a question.  Soon, (with just a little more reputation), you'll be able to upvote as many answers as you'd like, too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\rm mod\ 9\!:\ \ 2^3\equiv\, -1\:\Rightarrow\:2^{15}\equiv -1\:\Rightarrow\:2^{17}\!\equiv -4\:\Rightarrow\:mod\ 18\!:\,\ 2^{17}\equiv \color{#C00}{-4} $

$\rm mod\ 19\!:\ 2^{18}\!\equiv1\:\Rightarrow\:2^{\large 2^{17}}\!\!\!\equiv 2^{\,\large{(2^{17}\, mod\ 18)}}\!\equiv 2^{\color{#C00}{-4}}\equiv \dfrac{1}{16}\equiv \dfrac{1}{{-}3}\equiv \dfrac{6}{-18}\equiv\, 6$.

Answer (score 1):

Direct computation *modulo $19$* should be straightforward: you just square $2$ seventeen times, then add $1$. Don't compute in the integers; that would be silly and the numbers would be gigantic.

You could do tricks with Fermat's little theorem as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using Fermat's Little Theorem, for any integer $a,$ prime $p$ and  $(a,p)=1,a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$

$\implies a^{(p-1)b}\equiv1^b\pmod p\equiv1$ for any integer $b$

$\implies a^{(p-1)b+c}\equiv a^c\pmod p$ for any integer $c$

$\implies a^x\equiv a^y\pmod p$ if $(p-1)\mid (x-y)$

$2^3=8\equiv-1\pmod 9, 2^{15}\equiv(-1)^5\pmod 9\equiv-1\implies 2^{15}=9k-1$

So, $2^{17}=4(9k-1)\equiv -4\pmod{18}\equiv14$ for prime $p=19$

$$\text{So, }2^{2^{17}}\equiv 2^{14}\pmod{19}\text{ as }2^{17}\equiv14\pmod{18}$$

$2^4=16\equiv-3\pmod{19}\implies 2^{12}=(2^4)^3\equiv(-3)^3\pmod{19}\equiv-8$

So, $2^{14}=4\cdot2^{12}\equiv4\cdot(-8)\pmod{19}\equiv6$